# "Haber + estado + adjetivo" en relación del presente

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales, pretérito-perfecto, tiempos-pasados

**En pocas palabras:** ¿Es correcto que "Haber + estado + adjetivo" es sólo para un tiempo en el pasado, y si lo usas, no puede ser en el presente también? ¿Y qué tiempo es este?

¡Hola!

Yo estaba escuchando un podcast (se llama "Coffee Break Spanish"), y uno de los anfitriones dijo algo interesante.

(Enlace del episodio está [aquí](https://radiolingua.com/2011/07/cbs-show-time-spanish-lesson-11/), y la parte de que hablo está a 19:40 del episodio)

Él dijo "en ingles, "Haber + estado + adjetivo" podría estar sólo en el pasado (e.g. He has been sick, but is now well), o podría estar en el pasado y en el presente (e.g. He has been sick, and still is).

Pero, y esto es la razón de mi pregunta, él dijo que *en español* "Haber + estado + adjetivo" es sólo para el pasado. Si alguien dice "Él ha estado enfermo," es incorrecto si él esta enfermo todavía. Si "él" ha estado enfermo, y *todavía* está enfermo, hay que decir "Él *está* enfermo *desde hace* tres semanas" (por ejemplo).

Yo hablé con uno de mis amigos que habla español en esto, y él dijo que no está seguro, pero es posible. Pero él me dijo que la frase "Ha estado corrido" es posible estar en el presente y en el pasado también.

No hace falta decir, estoy un poco confundido. ¿Alguien sabe cómo funcionan estas frases? No he encontrado esta descripción en otros lugares, pero no sé suficiente de la gramática para investigar más.

(Por cierto, estoy aprendiendo español, y por eso por favor discúlpame por cualquier error que encuentres. Podría explicar más si es necesario)

Comment: Ojalá y nos des un enlace y timestamp para el episodio donde se trató este tema, pero por lo pronto, pues no me parece bien lo que aparentemente se dijo en ese podcast.  Por otra parte creo que falta una palabrita en una frase -- creo que debe ser "está enfermo desde **hace** tres semanas".  Otra cosita: "Él está enfermo hace dos años" no se puede decir así.  Una posible corrección sería "Él se enfermó hace dos años" o quizás "Está enfermo desde hace dos años" o "Ha estado enfermo por dos años."

Comment: @aparente001 en el español de España otra opción es "lleva dos años enfermo", para mí es como suena más natural. La pregunta es curiosa porque si me dicen "ha estado los dos últimos años enfermo" no me queda claro si aún lo está o no.

Comment: "Lleva dos años enfermo" tambien se puede usar en America Latina. @Charlie.

Comment: @aparente001 gracias por la respuesta. Yo añadí el enlace y timestamp. Además, yo corregí el ejemplo sobre "desde hace" (Yo escuché al episodio otra vez y di cuenta que yo recordé incorrecto)

Comment: @Charlie gracias por la respuesta. Yo sé "lleva dos años" (y me encanta), pero mi pregunta es, si usas el pasado perfecto, ¿puede ser la verdad en el presente también? ¿O es incorrecto?

Comment: Me di cuenta que no estoy seguro si esto es el tiempo pasado perfecto, y reemplacé el descripción con "Haber + estado + adjetivo"

Comment: Gracias por el enlace y timestamp.  No estoy de acuerdo con el radiolocutor.  Mira aqui: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32367/9385.  Avisa si todavia te queda alguna duda.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preterito Perfecto v Preterite](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32367/preterito-perfecto-v-preterite)

Comment: @aparente001 "Está enfermo hace dos años" no es un error, aunque suele escucharse más "Hace dos años **que** está enfermo".

Comment: @pablodf76 Nunca lo habia escuchado asi, pero si tu dices, bien.

Comment: @aparente001 Sí, parece que estás correcto. SpanishDict dice [aquí](https://www.spanishdict.com/guide/spanish-present-perfect-indicative) que "The present perfect may be used to talk about an action still in progress, but it's also common to use the present tense to do this."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu propia respuesta (y [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32367/24236) a la que te han dirigido en los comentarios) dicen correctamente que el **pretérito perfecto compuesto** (*haber+participio*) se usa para referirse a acciones que ocurrieron en un pasado cercano **o que tienen un efecto en el presente**. En la mayoría de los casos, este efecto es una consecuencia de la acción:

- Hoy ya he comido (*y por tanto no tengo que comer ahora*)

En algunos casos, el pretérito perfecto compuesto también puede indicar que la acción continúa en el presente:

- He vivido tres meses en esta ciudad
- He estado enfermo una semana

Pero esto es ambiguo y poco común. La palabra *[perfecto](https://dle.rae.es/perfecto)*, en el nombre del tiempo, significa

> **perfecto, ta**
>
> [...]
>
> 4. adj. Gram. [perfectivo](https://dle.rae.es/perfectivo).

es decir,

> **perfectivo, va**
>
> [...]
>
> 2. adj. Gram. Que expresa acción terminada.

Los tiempos *perfectos* indican casi siempre acciones terminadas, y por tanto es preferible utilizar una de las otras construcciones que te han propuesto en los comentarios

- Llevo tres meses viviendo en esta ciudad
- Estoy enfermo desde hace una semana

Cuando yo uso el pretérito perfecto compuesto para expresar acciones o estados que continúan en el presente, casi siempre tengo que eliminar la ambigüedad aclarando explícitamente que continúan en el presente:

- He estado enfermo una semana. Todavía no me he recuperado.

Answer (score 1):

Con los comentarios de mi pregunta, he podido investigar este tema más, y todo lo que he encontrado parece decir lo contrario del podcast.

Un [artículo de SpanishDict del pretérito perfecto (Present Perfect)](https://www.spanishdict.com/guide/spanish-present-perfect-indicative) dice esto:

> The Spanish present perfect (el pretérito perfecto compuesto o el
>   antepresente) is used to talk about things that started in the past
>   ***and which continue or repeat in the present***. It's also used to talk
>   about things that have happened in the recent past.

Un artículo de ThoughtCo se llama [‘Haber’ and ‘Estar’ Used in Forming Compound Past Tenses](https://www.thoughtco.com/haber-and-estar-compound-past-tenses-3079911) dice esto:

> In general, the present perfect tense is used to discuss actions that
>   took place in the past but still have relevance to the present ***or are
>   continuing up to the present***.

Curiosamente, este artículo de Real Fast Spanish, que se llama [How to Use the Spanish Present Perfect Tense](https://www.realfastspanish.com/vocabulary/spanish-phrases-that-trigger-the-present-perfect-tense), dice el completo opuesto del podcast que escuché:

> To reiterate, any event that started in the past and continues into
>   the present moment ***requires*** the use of the present perfect tense.

¡Gracias a todos por su ayuda!