# "Le dije que ella lo hiciera para que él lo supiera" y alternativas en el uso de los tiempos verbales

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

Escribí varias oraciones para entender secuencia de tiempos y como se puede combinar.

Creo que estas oraciones que escribí son correctas:

*Le **pedí** que ella lo **hiciera** para que él **supiera** que todo **estaba** bien*

*Le **pedí** que ella lo **hiciera** para que él **supiera** que todo **estaría** bien*

*Le **pedí** que ella lo **hiciera** para que él **sepa** que todo **está** bien"*

*Le **pido** que ella lo **haga** para que él **sepa** que todo **está** bien*

No estoy seguro de que sea posible escribir así. Creo que no es posible:

*Le **pedí** que ella lo **haga** para que él **sepa** que todo **está** bien*

*Le **pido** que ella lo **hiciera** para que él **sepa** que todo **está** bien*

¿Es correcto lo que escribí?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todas las frases incluyen cuatro acciones:

- **pedir**: *pedí* quiere decir que la petición ocurrió en el pasado, y *pido* quiere decir que está ocurriendo en el presente
- **hacer**: las frases con *hiciera* indican que se pidió que la acción se realizara en el pasado, y las frases con *haga* indican que la acción pedida debe realizarse en el presente o futuro.
- **saber**: el objetivo de la acción pedida es que él *supiera* algo (en el pasado) o que lo *sepa* (en el presente o futuro).
- **estar**: lo que él tiene que saber es que todo *estaba* bien (en el pasado), o que *está* bien (en el presente). El condicional *estaría* en la frase 2 es un "futuro desde una perspectiva pasada", es decir, todo no estaba bien en el momento de hablar, pero más tarde sí.

Se pueden hacer muchas combinaciones con estos tiempos, y en particular las frases 1, 2, 3 y 4 son correctas.

En la frase 5,

> Le pedí que ella lo haga para que él sepa que todo está bien

se ha pedido en el pasado que algo se haga en el presente. Esto normalmente (aunque no siempre) indica que la petición ha ocurrido en un pasado cercano. En este caso, aunque la frase es correcta, [en España](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32368/24236) se utilizaría más el pretérito perfecto compuesto:

> Le **he pedido** que ella lo haga para que él sepa que todo está bien

En la sexta frase:

> Le pido que ella lo hiciera para que él sepa que todo está bien

se pide en el presente que se haga algo en el pasado. Esto no es posible, por lo que la frase es incorrecta.

Answer (score 1):

El español es mi lengua materna, pero no soy un experto en gramática. A mí me parece que todas esas oraciones están bien excepto la última, aunque no sé explicar qué hay de erróneo en ella.