# Is the preterite more common in Mexican Spanish than the present perfect?

Tags: gramática, méxico, pretérito-imperfecto, pretérito-perfecto, tiempos-pasados

[*en inglés*]

While learning Spanish, I have spent the time to get
familiar with the grammar.  While far from fluent, the
dialect I primarily need to focus on is that of Mexico.
One aspect of this that I’ve heard is that in Mexican
Spanish it’s far more common to use the Preterite than
the Present Perfect forms.  Is this true, especially in
the states near the border and the Río Grande valley?

For example, to say *I spoke*, you could also say *I
have spoken*, but would the first version
be more commonly said than the second?

1. Yo hablé.  (*more common?*)
2. He hablado. (*rarer?*)

Or if someone wanted to say *I went to the store*, this
could also be said as *I have gone to the store* with a
slightly different but still more or less the same meaning.
For example:

3. Fui a la tienda. (*more common?*)
4. He ido a la tienda. (*rarer?*)

Does Mexican Spanish prefer the simple past tense even
where other Spanish-speaking regions might be more apt
to use the compound version with *haber*?

Comment: See https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32367/pret%c3%a9rito-perfecto-v-preterite

Comment: I went to the store and I have gone to the store don't mean exactly the same thing in English.  While some native English speakers might use them interchangeably, that's an idiosyncarasy, and not really part of the language as asuch.

Comment: Allow me to give you some advice: don't confuse the fact that Spanish structure is the same everywhere and it is only the vocabulary and idioms and accent that differ. And he hablado and hablé are not interchangeable in any Spanish. Just as in English, as Walter Mitty has pointed out.

Comment: @WalterMitty European Spanish and European English are both more apt to use the present perfect than the simple past for recent events with continued applicability to the present. This contrasts, sometimes strongly, with what's more common in the Americas for both languages. *Did you eat yet?* vs *Have you eaten yet?*

Comment: What I may add is that in Spanish America we tend to use simple verb tenses as opposed to Spanish from Spain. Instead of saying "He visto a tu padre hoy" we tend to use "Vi a tu padre hoy".

Answer (score 0):

No hay ningún ‘presente perfecto’ en español. Se llama ‘pretérito **compuesto**’, y es equivalente al pretérito simple. La diferencia entre el pretérito simple y el compuesto es meramente estilística.

Los españoles son un poco más propensos a utilizar el pretérito compuesto. En América, no lo usamos demasiado. Lo usan un poco los periodistas y los ciudadanos comunes cuando la conversación se vuelve un poco más formal.

No les creas a los que te hablen de que existe el ‘presente perfecto’ en castellano; la mayoría de los que hablan de esas cosas le rinden culto a una serie de dictums que provienen de un corpus armado en base a calcos de las reglas gramaticales del inglés. No hay ninguna evidencia empírica de que el uso de ambos tiempos verbales (*present perfect* y pretérito compuesto) sean equivalentes. Por lo tanto, toda teoría que afirme lo contrario [es un gigante de pies de barro metiéndose en la laguna, se va a caer!](https://youtu.be/4Ci_zteGP4c?feature=shared&t=40) Ni siquiera la casta habla sobre la existencia de un ‘presente perfecto’ como parte de los tiempos verbales.

Mi recomendación (siendo argentino): preferir el pretérito simple, con eso vas a lograr mayor **fluidez** y **entropía**, dos cualidades que son súper valoradas para la comunicación en los tiempos que corren. Por supuesto que sería poco elegante hacerlo totalmente, pero calculá un 90% de las veces pretérito simple vs. un 10% de las veces pretérito compuesto. En cualquier caso, no te preocupes por haber utilizado un tiempo u otro. No hay ninguna regla estricta sobre cuál debe ser usado.

[Acá se explica más a fondo](https://www.memoria.fahce.unlp.edu.ar/trab_eventos/ev.11177/ev.11177.pdf). Es para el español ríoplatense pero yo opino que son muy generalizables las conclusiones que obtiene la autora: lo que determina el uso del compuesto es la persistencia psicológica (no temporal) del evento acontecido o la elección deliberada del tiempo como recurso retórico.

Answer (score 0):

Al igual que en inglés, el significado de *hablé* y *he hablado* en español no son exactamente equivalentes, y aunque en muchas situaciones sea posible intercambiar las formas verbales, no hay una forma verbal rara ni formas verbales preferidas. Depende del contexto.  Asunto aparte es, si aquí o allá, se abusa de una forma u otra.

El pretérito perfecto compuesto es un pasado reciente, de actualidad, con consecuencias en el presente,  y pretérito perfecto simple es un pasado más indefinido, más alejado en el tiempo y menos relevante para el presente.  La [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/) define al primero así:

> Tiempo perfectivo que sitúa la acción, el proceso o el estado expresados por el verbo en un momento anterior al presente en un lapso **no concluido**.

Compare estas frases:

> Trump ha hablado con Biden.

> Trump habló con Biden.

Si Trump habló con Biden hace solo una horas, es una noticia de actualidad y se pueden emplear ambas frases, pero la primera frase tiene mucho más sentido, porque si la conversación fue hace mucho tiempo, digamos antes de las elecciones de 2012, la primera frase no tiene sentido. Nadie diría en el 2034 «Trump ha hablado con Biden en el 2012» sino «Trump habló con Biden en el 2012».

Otro ejemplo:

> Nerón ha hablado con Claudio.

Es seguro que Nerón no ha hablado con Claudio. Ambos murieron hace siglos, RIP. Solo en el contexto de una novela o una película histórica alguien podría decir algo así. Pero un historiador sí  podría decir

> Nerón habló con Claudio (cuando estaban vivos, obviamente).

En el contexto de un libro o una conferencia sobre la historia del Imperio Romano, Nerón no ha hablado, hablaba o habló, no había cantado, cantaba, o cantó:

> Nerón cantó tocando su lira.

Traducción: El emperador romano hizo el ridículo delante de los senadores. Pero eso ya a nadie le importa un comino.

> Nerón ha cantado tocando su lira.

Traducción: Un payaso con túnica y corona de laurel acaba de hacer el ridículo delante de los jueces de *Got Talent* y ahora mismo no estamos partiendo de risa.

En estos hipotéticos contextos (bueno, el primero no es hipotético, realmente Nerón cantaba) las frases no son intercambiables. En español, sólo son  realmente  intercambiables las dos formas del pretérito imperfecto («hablara» vs. «hablase»). Asunto aparte es si luego sabemos escoger bien entre tanta variedad. `:)`